# Custom UISearchBar hides when is active iOS

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

i am developing an app ios7, got a custom UISearchBar at top of a UITableView with an UISegmetedControl, the problem is when i start to search, searchBar goes left and hide, so is imposible to handle it, how can i make the UISearchBar stay on it's position??

Comment: Can you post you code?

Comment: i'm using only storyboard, can't upload a photo, UISearchBar at left, UISegmetedControl at right, same line..that is it

Comment: You can also post your implementation file's code,rather than upload a photo.

Comment: Thanks, i have solved it moving UISegmentedControl  as tableViewHeader